# Two-way rsync between two servers

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, rsync, batch-file

I read about rsync but I want to ask how can I do the following by rsync:

I have two files in to different machine (UNIX-AIX) and have the same name.

```
server1 : ..../file.txt
server2 : ..../file.txt
```

I want to apply the following in two server to make sure I have the latest version of `file.txt` on each server.

server1:

```
if (mod-time[file.txt (on server 1] > mod-time[file.txt (on server2)] )
 { 
   update file.txt (on server 2 ) to become as file.txt (on server 1) ;
 }
else
 {
  skip ;
 }
```

server2:

```
if (mod-time[file.txt (on server2)] > mod-time[file.txt (on server1)] )
 {  
   update file.txt (on server 1 ) to become as file.txt (on server 2) ;
}
else
{
   skip ;    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/). It's two-way file synchronization software. [Documentation](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html#local).

Sooner or later you have to handle collisions (someone/something modified both files - are you going to merge changes or just overwrite older version).

Also, you might want to use (depending on your use) some version control system to synchronize changes.

Comment: overwrite older version

Comment: please from where i can download Unix verion please you can give me direct link ????

Comment: @Mohammed: click the word "Unison" in Olli's answer. On the Unison home page click the link "downloads" in the menu on the left.

Comment: yes ... but i don't know which option i will use to UNIX ?

Comment: @Mohammed: well, this one: http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison//download/releases/stable/ , but you have to compile it by yourself. You should refer documentation (linked on my answer).

Comment: Unison is no longer under active development--I'm not sure when they officially stopped: http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/status.html